# Getting NullPointerException while creating a game

Tags: java

I'm creating a game.  It doesn't throw an error in Eclipse, but when I run it in debug mode it throws a `NullPointerException` at line:

```
System.out.println("Stone x: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getX() + " y: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getY());
```

Game.java:

```
package lt.projecturanium;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import lt.projecturanium.blocks.Block;
import lt.projecturanium.blocks.BlockRectangle;
import lt.projecturanium.entity.Player;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JFrame _frame;
    public static Game _instance;

    private static final String TITLE = "Project Uranium";
    private static final int WIDTH = 650;
    private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH * 3 / 4;

    private static final int UPDATE_RATE = 50;
    private static final int RENDER_RATE = 100;

    public static HashMap<Block, Coordinates> blocks = new HashMap<Block, Coordinates>();

    public int rectx = 0;
    public int recty = 0;
    public int rectID = 0;

    public boolean hitted = false;

    public float interpolation;

    public static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    private Thread _thread;

    private boolean _running;

    private int _totalTicks = 0;
    private int _tps = 0;
    private int _fps = 0;

    public Game()
    {
        _instance = this;
        setPreferredSize(SIZE);
        setMinimumSize(SIZE);
        setMaximumSize(SIZE);

        _frame = new JFrame(TITLE);

        _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        _frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        _frame.add(_instance, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        _frame.pack();

        _frame.setResizable(false);
        _frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        _frame.setVisible(true);
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        blocks.put(new Block(new BlockRectangle(200)), new Coordinates(30, 50));
    }
    public synchronized void start()
    {
        _running = true;
        _thread = new Thread(this, TITLE+"_main");
        _thread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        _running = false;
        if (_thread != null)
        {
            try {
                _thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  // fixes the immediate problem.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString("FPS: " + _fps + "\n TPS: " + _tps, 10, 10);
        if (hitted)
        {
            recty = 0;
            rectx += 21;
            rectID++;
            blocks.put(new Block(new BlockRectangle(rectID)), new Coordinates(rectx, recty));
            hitted = false;
        }
        recty++;
        g2.drawImage(Player.getTexture(), 60, 60, null);
        g2.drawRect(rectx, recty, 20, 20);
        g2.setColor(new Color(101, 67, 33));
        g2.fillRect(0, 430, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2.setColor(new Color(0, 100, 0));
        g2.fillRect(0, 420, getWidth(), 10);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (recty == (419 - 20))
        {   
            hitted = true;
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        double lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
        double lastRenderTime = lastUpdateTime;
        final int ns = 1000000000;
        final double nsPerUpdate = (double) ns / UPDATE_RATE;
        final double nsPerRender = (double) ns / RENDER_RATE;
        final int maxUpdatesBeforeRender = 5;

        int lastSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / ns);
        int tickCount = 0;
        int renderCount = 0;
        while (_running) {

          long currTime = System.nanoTime();
          int tps = 0;

          while ((currTime - lastUpdateTime) > nsPerUpdate && tps < maxUpdatesBeforeRender) {
            update();
            tickCount++;
            _totalTicks++;
            tps++;
            lastUpdateTime += nsPerUpdate;
            interpolation = Math.min(1.0F, (float) ((currTime - lastUpdateTime) / nsPerUpdate));
            render(interpolation, getGraphics());
          }

          if (currTime - lastUpdateTime > nsPerUpdate) {
            lastUpdateTime = currTime - nsPerUpdate;
          }
          if (currTime - lastRenderTime == maxUpdatesBeforeRender + 1)
          {
              render(interpolation, getGraphics());
          }
          renderCount++;
          lastRenderTime = currTime;

          int currSecond = (int) (lastUpdateTime / ns);
          if (currSecond > lastSecond) {
            _tps = tickCount;
            _fps = renderCount;
            tickCount = 0;
            renderCount = 0;
            lastSecond = currSecond;
            _frame.setTitle(TITLE + " | TPS: " + _tps + " | FPS: "+ _fps);

          }

          while (currTime - lastRenderTime < nsPerRender && currTime - lastUpdateTime < nsPerUpdate) {
            Thread.yield();
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currTime = System.nanoTime();
          }
        }   
      }
    public void update()
    {
        _frame.pack();
    }
    public void render(float interp, Graphics g)
    {
        BufferStrategy myStrategy = getBufferStrategy(); 
        Graphics gra = myStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        paint(gra);
        g.dispose();
        myStrategy.show();
        //System.out.println("Grass x: " + blocks.get("grass").getX() + " y: " + blocks.get("grass").getY());
        System.out.println("Stone x: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getX() + " y: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getY());
    }
}
```

BlockRectangle.java:

```
package lt.projecturanium.blocks;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import lt.projecturanium.Game;

public class BlockRectangle extends Block{
    private int id;
    private static HashMap<Integer, BlockRectangle> rects = new HashMap<Integer, BlockRectangle>();
    public BlockRectangle(int id)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        rects.put(id, this);
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public static BlockRectangle getByID(int id)
    {
        return rects.get(id);
    }
    public static Image getTexture()
    {
        try{        
            return ImageIO.read(Game._instance.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../res/player.png"));   
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Block.java:

package lt.projecturanium.blocks;

```
public class Block {
    private Block block;
    public Block (Block block){
        this.block = block;
    }
    public Block getBlock() {
        return block;
    }
    public Block getBlockById(int id)
    {
        return block;
    }
    public Block()
    {

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Thread [Project Uranium_main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    Game.render(float, Graphics) line: 186  
    Game.run() line: 139    
    Thread.run() line: not available
```

Comment: Can you add the error output to the question?

Comment: `I think you know that i'm creating a game.` -- Didn't know thus far, but will keep a note of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't throw an error in Eclipse"? Do you mean that Eclipse doesn't report a compilation error? You are debugging it within Eclipse, right?

Comment: Yes, i mean when you are in editor, it doesn't show the error.

Comment: Yeah we could do with the stack trace.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error in Eclipse because this is a run-time error, not a compile-time error.  The code is syntactically correct to compile, but when it runs there's a logical error somewhere.  This particular error means that one of the items on that line is `null` and can't be used.  It's *probably* the variable `blocks` (or, more likely, whatever the `.get()` method on `blocks` returns) but I can't be certain from here.  It looks like you're trying to use a variable before you've assigned anything to it.

Comment: Since you know the line with the NPE, you can start breaking down that line into smaller chunks to determine what's null. For example, is the item in `BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)` null? Or maybe the x coordinate?

Comment: Somewhy it's not working

Comment: Oops, deleted because I saw the code in `paint()` and thought that might have made my comment invalid.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Begin debugging by looking at the individual values that could be null.  You could use this block as an example:

```
BlockRectangle blockRectangle = BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID);
System.out.println("BlockRectangle: " + blockRectangle);
Coordinates coordinates= blocks.get(blockRectangle);
System.out.println("Coordinates: " + coordinates);
System.out.println("X: " + coordinates.getX());
System.out.println("Y: " + coordinates.getY());
```

Once you've determined what is null, you can start back-tracking through your code to determine why there isn't a value set where you're expecting one to be.

Comment: I determined that is Coordinates.

Comment: That's a good first step--now you know that when you call blocks.get(blockRectangle), you are getting a null value back. Since you are using a HashMap, there are two possible reasons to get null: either the key (blockRectangle) doesn't exist, or the key exists, but was assigned a null value.  You can determine this by iterating through the Map and printing what it contains.  You'll also want to look at where you're assigning values into your blocks HashMap to make sure 1) actually calling the code at some point, 2) not inserting null values if you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

What a weird programming ...

However, the problem seems to be sitting here:

1) In class `Game` you have a static field of type `HashMap<Block, Coordinates>` called *blocks*. You are inserting instances of class `Block` for the keys into that map. Corresponding line is:

```
blocks.put(new Block(new BlockRectangle(rectID)), new Coordinates(rectx, recty));
```

2) While also creating an instace of type `BlockRectangle` in the same line, the constructor puts the object in construction as a key into the the static field of type `HashMap<Integer, BlockRectangle>` called *rects*. Corresponding line is:

```
rects.put(id, this);
```

3) Then you are trying to get a Block by calling

```
blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID))
```

The inner expression `BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)` will return a `BlockRectangle` instance that is looked up in the map *rects*. With this instance now a lookup is done in the map *blocks*, but this only stores `Block`s as keys, not `BlockRectangle`s (see point 1).

Without any `equals` (and `hashCode`) method in `Block` and `BlockRectangle`, you are not getting any further. But implementing those methods in any of these classes make it worse, as it will not be a good idea to compare blocks with block rectangles.

You should do a complete redesign of your software.

Comment: Ok, I changed the HashMap in BlockRectangle to HashMap<Integer, Block>, but nothing changed..

Comment: Changing the map in BlockRectangle to HashMap<Integer, Block> does not change anything, as you still store BlockRectangle instances as values inside this map. Maybe you could change the other map to HashMap<BlockRectangle, Coordinates>, and then you should not create a "new Block(...)" that wraps a BlockRectangle, but just use the newly created BlockRectangle as the key. I do not know, if that works. Maybe you know someone, who could work with you on a serious redesign.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception is where your code is trying to do something with a value, but the value is null. A value is null usually because either it isn't instantiated `Object o = new Object` or you're pulling from a data source, where the desired record  doesn't exist it will return a null. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

In your case, you're getting a NPE in the line `System.out.println("Stone x: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getX() + " y: " + blocks.get(BlockRectangle.getByID(rectID)).getY());` because the Map is returning a null BlockRectangle object.

Regarding you're comment on @GamerJosh's answer, your error is in the coordinates, which I'm going to guess is because you're returning a null BlockRectangle from the `getById()`. Think about it like this: you never increment/change your rectId field, but add the first object to have an Id of `200`. Other than that, you add new Blocks with Id of `0` in your paint() method. But what would happen if you get to this logging statement before those other blocks would be in your map? What would your map return for Id `0` if the only record in there has an id of `200`?

That being said, I don't think keeping a map of all BlockRectangles is the greatest program design. Instead, consider having a variable in your main class that keeps track of all that.

PS. You're English is very good and it's exciting to know that you're getting into programming at a young age! Also, since you're making a game, I would like to point out the [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/?as=1%20Game%20Development) site where you can ask game specific questions, like game design or programming questions that game makers might have a bit more insight into.

Comment: Okey, i will check that :) Thank you for answer :)

Comment: Your Map is static but your BlockRectangle class isn't.

Comment: getByID() class is static ?

Comment: Emm, BlockRectangle isn't null: BlockRectangle: lt.projecturanium.blocks.BlockRectangle@15e538e

Comment: IF you're BlockRectange isn't null, then there is an issue when associating the BlockRectangle with Coordinates. to see why this is happening, check out @Seelenvirtuose's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws the NullPointerException no matter where you run it. It's just that throwing this exception in the `run` method of a thread can only be catched in two ways: Either by catching it explicitly with `try {...} catch(NullPointerException e) {...}` or with defining an `uncaughtExceptionHandler()` of the Thread.

The `run` method I not necessarily your `run` but the one defined to call paint an rendering.

Depending on what RuntimeExceptions you expect, you either define such an exception handler or you eliminate the cause of the exception. In your case one of the `get` methods do not find an element and return null.