# Why i can't initialize variable in parent class' constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

[Reason behind not getting compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwzio.png)
[image]

Hello there, as you can see below in image that i have inherited from my parent class but i'm unable to make objects of either class can anyone help me out?

Comment: post copy-pastable code!

Comment: The compiler error tells you a lot. Have you bothered reading it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827888/implicit-super-constructor-block-is-undefined)

Answer (score 4):

read the message of the error of the compiler!

> Implicit super constructor Base() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke
>   another constructor

your child class must call the constructor of the parent class

```
Child(int b) {
    super(b);
    this.b = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor has to be public. You have declared a protected type constructor hence it is not getting treated as a constructor to be accessed from  your main function

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are `private`.

Comment: I thought they are supposed to be package protected.

Comment: Ha. You win. I answered this as a C++ question. Have an upvote.

Comment: This isn't the problem. If they're all in the same file and they're package private (which they are), then they are accessible.